Connection between KdV and CFT
I am a pedestrian in $1+1$-dimensional CFT. As far as I know, there is a connection to show the integrability of the $1+1$ CFT through the conserved charges of the KdV hierarchy, namely, the charges of the latter correspond to generators of the enveloping algebra of Virasoro. In this regard, I have two questions:

Can someone concretize the previous discussion, showing the procedures of the above statement, or discuss about the consequences and/or scope?

Beyond the integrability of the CFT itself, are there any other connections between integrable systems and CFTs?



Integrable structures of 1+1d CFTs are a vast topic, but let me try to point out some of the basic key points. Here I'll consider the case of a relativistic 1+1d CFT on a cylinder, with space coordinate $x\sim x+2\pi$ and time coordinate $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (but there are variants for other topologies and signatures).
Stress-energy tensor and Virasoro algebra: One of the key ingredients of the CFT is the chiral left-moving component of its stress-energy tensor $T(x)$. This is a local spin-2 field whose time evolution is governed by the chirality equation $\partial_t T = \partial_x T$. Its time dependence is then simply that of a left-moving field $T(x+t)$ (in addition, there is also an independent right-moving component $\bar{T}(x-t)$, but here I'll focus on the left-moving sector of the CFT). The field $T$
satisfies the commutation relation
$$ \bigl[T(x), T(y)\bigr] = 2\mathrm{i}\pi \left( \bigl( T(x) + T(y) \bigr) \delta'(x-y) - \frac{c}{12} \delta'''(x-y) \right)\,,\tag{1}\label{CR}$$
where $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is the central charge of the theory. In terms of the Fourier modes expansion
$$ T(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} L_{-n}\, e^{inx} - \frac{c}{24}\,,\tag{2}\label{modes}$$
this is equivalent to the Virasoro algebra
$$ \bigl[ L_n, L_m \bigr] = (n-m)\,L_{n+m} + \frac{c}{12}n(n^2-1)\,\delta_{n+m,0}\,.$$
Integrable structure and KdV hierarchy: This Virasoro algebra admits an integrable structure, i.e. an infinite set of commuting conserved operators. Here I'll focus on commuting higher-spin local charges of the form
$$ I_{2n-1} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} U_{2n}(x)\,\text{d}x \,,\tag{3}\label{IoM}$$
where the densities $U_{2n}(x)$ are composite fields of spin $2n$ built from $T(x)$ and its derivatives. The first few of these densities are
$$ U_2(x) = T(x)\,, \qquad\quad U_4(x) =\; :\!T(x)^2\!:\,,\tag{4}\label{U}$$
$$ U_6(x) =\; :\!T(x)^3\!: \, +\; \frac{c+2}{12} :\partial_xT(x)^2:\,,$$
where $:\,:$ denotes the normal ordering of fields on the cylinder. More generally, we have
$$U_{2n}(x) = \; :\!T(x)^n\!: \,+\; \dots\,,$$
where the dots correspond to terms involving at least one derivative of $T(x)$. The main property of the densities $U_{2n}(x)$ is the following: their commutation relations, which follow from the one \eqref{CR} of $T(x)$, are such that their integral pairwise commute. In other words:
$$ \bigl[ I_{2n-1}, I_{2m-1} \bigr] = 0\,, \qquad\quad \forall \, n,m\,.$$
This means that the theory admits an infinite number of commuting conserved quantities, which is a typical feature of integrability. These quantities $I_{2n-1}$ form what we call the Integrals of Motion (IoM) of the quantum KdV hierarchy. Note that there also exists an independent tower of charges $I_{-(2n-1)}$ of negative spins, built in a similar fashion from the right-moving field $\bar{T}(x)$.
KdV hierarchy in terms of modes: The IoM $I_{2n-1}$ are defined as local  integrals \eqref{IoM}. Using the Fourrier expansion \eqref{modes} of $T(x)$, one can express them in terms of the Virasoro modes $L_n$. For instance, the first two charges read
$$ I_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} T(x)\,\text{d}x = L_0 - \frac{c}{24} $$
$$ I_3 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} :\!T(x)^2\!:\,\text{d}x = L_0^2 + 2\sum_{n>0} L_{-n}\,L_n - \frac{c+2}{12} L_0 + \frac{c(5c+22)}{2880} $$
These can be interpreted as commuting elements of the universal envelopping algebra of Virasoro (or more rigorously an approprite completion thereof).
KdV equation: A natural question at that point is why do we call this integrable structure the KdV hierarchy. What is the relation with the KdV equation? The latter (in some conventions) is the non-linear PDE
$$\partial_u \phi = 6 \phi\, \partial_x \phi - \epsilon\,\partial_x^3 \phi \tag{5}\label{KdV}$$
obeyed by a function $\phi(x,u)$ of the spatial variable $x$ and the "KdV time" $u$, where $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ is the dispersion parameter.
To make the link with the construction above, we have to consider a standard feature of integrable hierarchies: since we have some commuting charges $I_{2n-1}$, we can take them as generators of some dynamical flows
$$ \partial_{u_n} = \mathrm{i} \bigl[ I_{2n-1}, \cdot \bigr]\,,$$
in the same way than the Hamiltonian $H$ generates the time evolution $\partial_t = \mathrm{i} [H,\cdot]$. Since the $I_{2n-1}$'s commute one with another, the corresponding flows all commute:
$$ [\partial_{u_n}, \partial_{u_m} ] = 0 \,,$$
ensuring that they are compatible and that we can look for common solutions of all these flows simultaneously. In particular, the flow of $T(x)$ is given by
$$ \partial_{u_n} T(x) = \frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \bigl[ T(x), U_{2n}(y) \bigr] \, \text{d}y \,.$$
The commutator in this integrand can be computed from the expression \eqref{U} of $U_{2n}$ in terms of $T$ and the algebra \eqref{CR} of the latter. For the first flow, one simply finds $\partial_{u_1} T = \partial_x T$, which is essentially trivial. The second flow is more interesting and reads
$$ \partial_{u_2} T = 6:\! T\,\partial_x T\!: \, - \; \frac{c-4}{6} \,\partial_x^3 T \,.\tag{6}\label{qKdV}$$
This is a quantum version of the KdV equation \eqref{KdV}, with the KdV field identified as $\phi = T$, the dispersion parameter as $\epsilon = \frac{c-4}{6}$ and the "KdV time" $u$ as $u_2$. In particular, note that this KdV time is not the same as the Minkowski time $t$ of the initial 1+1d CFT.
Note that by construction, all the commuting operators $I_{2n-1}$ of the CFT are conserved with respect to the KdV flow:
$$\partial_u I_{2n-1} = \mathrm{i} \bigl[ I_3, I_{2n-1} \bigr] = 0 \,.$$
The $I_{2n-1}$ are thus Integrals of Motion for the (quantum) KdV equation \eqref{qKdV}.
References: The main references for the quantum KdV hierarchy in CFTs are

Sasaki and Yamanaka, "Virasoro algebra, vertex operators, quantum
Sine-Gordon and solvable Quantum Field theories", Adv. Stud. in Pure
Math. 16, 271-296 (1988)

Eguchi and Yang: "Deformation of conformal field theories and soliton equations", Phys. Lett. B224, 373-378 (1989)

Kupershmidt and Mathieu, "Quantum KdV like equations and perturbed Conformal Field theories", Phys. Lett. B227, 245-250 (1989)

Bazhanov, Lukyanov and Zamolodchikov, "Integrable structure of
conformal field theory, quantum KdV theory and thermodynamic Bethe
ansatz", Commun. Math. Phys. 177 (1996) 381-398
[arXiv:hep-th\9412229]


See also the follow-up series of papers by Bazhanov, Lukyanov and Zamolodchikov.
Further directions: There are various directions for further developments on this topic.

Diagonalisation of the commuting operators $I_{2n-1}$ on the Hilbert space of the CFT and the so-called ODE/IQFT or ODE/IM correspondence
Integrable hierarchies for other CFTs (the quantum KdV hierarchy is essentially the simplest example of integrable structure in CFT, but there are other interesting ones, which are built in more complicated algebras than Virasoro, such as W-algebras)
Integrable massive deformations (perturbation of the CFT by a relevant operator, making the theory massive but preserving the integrability)

There are also other links between integrability and CFT (inluding in higher-dimensions). A non-exhaustive list includes:

the relation between Gaudin/Hitchin systems and WZW models
integrability in the AdS/CFT correpsondence
the AGT correspondence
conformal blocs as eigenvectors of integrable mechanic systems
...

